# Why is Seek being called on a stream that returns false from CanSeek?

Tags: c#, stream, biztalk

Interesting problem I ran into recently:

I implemented a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class (a wrapping stream for a custom streaming pipeline component) and some later testing had my pipeline throwing an exception.  The exception was thrown from a call to Seek which I had hardcoded to throw a [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx) due to my stream being a forward-only, non-writable stream implementation (CanSeek and CanWrite returning false, Position:set throwing an exception, nothing unusual).  The call to Seek was coming from unmanaged code, so I couldn't really debug into it too much.  All I could really tell was that Seek was being called on my [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) implementation even though I had CanSeek returning false and the user wasn't even checking CanSeek.

What's up with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the answers were found here: [Implementing a Seek Method in a Managed Streaming Pipeline Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267887%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

It turns out that way back when, there was no Position property.  So the way to get the current position of the stream pointer was to call `Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Current );`

Fascinating.  The old new thing again.

That page gave the Seek implementation required:

```
override public long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
{
   long pos = -1;

   switch(origin)
   {
      case SeekOrigin.Begin :
         pos = offset;
         break;
      case SeekOrigin.Current :
         pos = Position + offset;
         break;
      case SeekOrigin.End :
         break;
   }

   // We generally disallow seeking of the stream
   // However, in unmanaged code, many people use Seek(0,CURR) to retrieve    // the current position
   // Special case (that is, if Seek does not change position, do not 
   // throw an exception)
   if (pos==Position)
   {
      return pos;
   }
   else
   {
      throw new NotSupportedException("ForwardOnlyEventingReadStream does not support Seek()");
   }
}
```

And that was the entire solution.  Yay!